# Why internal server error? "xhr.js?b50d:184 POST http://localhost:3000/api/ 500 (Internal Server Error)" "Error: Request failed with status code 500"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, http, server

I'm building an app using data from the IGDB Api - link to docs:
https://api-docs.igdb.com/?javascript#authentication

I'm able to get the access token from the  first POST request, but the second seems to be erroring. I am able to get both POSTS through in Postman, so there is most likely something wrong with my formatting or syntax?
Here's my React App.jsx axios call:

```
getAll() {
    axios.post('/api/')
      .then(res => this.setState({list: res.data}))
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }
```

server/index.js:

```
app.post('/api/', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const token = await axios.post('https://id.twitch.tv/oauth2/token?client_id=**CLIENT_ID**&client_secret=**CLIENT_SECRET**&grant_type=client_credentials');
    if (!token) { console.log('Error: couldnt get token' ); return res.sendStatus(500)}
    const data = await axios.post('https://api.igdb.com/v4/games/', 'fields *;', { headers: { 'Client-ID': '**CLIENT_ID**', 'Authorization':'Bearer ' + token }});

    if (!data) { console.log('Error: couldnt get data' ); return res.sendStatus(500)}
    res.status(200).send(data);
  } catch(e) {
    console.log(e);
    res.sendStatus(500);
  }
});
```

Comment: Could you post the logs from your backend and frontend console?

Comment: You can give details of what error it shows you, maybe there is a problem when sending the data to the request. Did you try to use postman?